# Swift: use CommonCrypto with bridging header - unresolved identifier

Tags: swift, bridging-header, commoncrypto

I am trying to use `Cryptor` in Swift for iOS.

`Random.swift` contains the line `import CommonCrypto` which doesn't work for me. Somewhere I've read that CommonCrypto doesn't offer access to Swift classes so I created a bridging header.

The import still wasn't working but when I import UIKit to my Bridging Header it is available in my Swift class so I thought another import isn't necessary. However, CommonCrypto's `CCRandomGenerateBytes` still gives me an `Use of unresolved identifier` when called in Swift. Is there anything I am missing?

With import of CommonCrypto in Swift file
[image]

Without import of CommonCrypto in Swift file
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `#import <CommonCrypto/CommonRandom.h>` to your Bridging Header file.

Comment: Bro thanks a ton, can't yet tell if it's usable now but I added CommonRandom and after cleaning the project and re-building, all errors disappeared, seems to have solved :)